# How do I ensure the right HTML element is passed from JavaScript to my Rust function?

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen

If I create a Rust function with wasm_bindgen that accepts an `HtmlCanvasElement`, how do I make sure it fails when it gets to the Rust side?

JavaScript:

```
(async () => {
    const demo = await import('./pkg/demo').catch(console.error);
    demo.setCanvas('Hello Element!');  
})();
```

Rust:

```rust
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;
use web_sys::{console, HtmlCanvasElement};

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn setCanvas(canvas: &HtmlCanvasElement) {
    //  Why does this even get here? I didn't pass in an HtmlCanvasElement
    console::log_1(&canvas);
}
```

It looks like I'm getting the type `HtmlCanvasElement` but if I try to use it as an `HtmlCanvasElement`, it doesn't have the functions because I'm passing in a string instead of the actual canvas element. I want it to fail when I set it, not at some later time when I try to use it.

Comment: There's not much type control at the boundary between the DOM and Rust in wasm_bindgen. I think it's the job of an additional lib or framework (which can be small and your own, you don't *have* to use another crate for that).

Comment: I don't even know where to go to look on how to check to see if it is indeed a canvas object in my code.

Comment: In most cases, you can check using `dyn_into` (like [this](https://github.com/Canop/wasm-tictactoe/blob/master/src/domus.rs#L38))

Comment: #[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn setElement(canvas: HtmlCanvasElement) -> Result<(), JsValue> {

  match canvas.dyn_into::<HtmlCanvasElement>() ...
...  This seems strange to dyn cast it to the same type

Comment: Thank you so much for this! While I don't understand what's going on here, it does work.  Where would you suggest I go to read more about the inner workings on why this works?

Comment: I'll make an answer with some references, as it looks like it solves your problem, OK ?

Comment: Yes, that's great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not much type control at the boundary between the DOM and Rust in wasm_bindgen. The JavaScript part handles what is seen from Rust as `JsValue`.

It means you have to do the checked conversions yourself (or let a future lib or framework do it for you).

The [`JsCast` trait](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/wasm_bindgen/trait.JsCast.html) helps for this. It lets you write this for example:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn setElement(canvas: JsValue) -> Result<(), JsValue> {
    match canvas.dyn_into::<HtmlCanvasElement>() {
        Ok(canvas) => {
            // ...

            Ok(())
        }
        Err(_) => Err(JsValue::from_str("argument not a HtmlCanvas")),
    }
}
```